# What does this JavaScript expression mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, react-navigation

I am working with [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params) and I can't figure out the meaning of this syntax.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.post) { <<<<<WHAT IS THIS ?
      // Post updated, do something with `route.params.post`
      // For example, send the post to the server
    }
  }, [route.params?.post]);
```

Does it work like obect.**doesPropertyExist**.subProperty or something else?

---

I have tried going through MDN documentation but can't find any reference to this type of syntax. I am not able to use similar syntax on a random object in my node REPL.

Comment: it's optional.chaining, simply means `if(route.params.post)` then do something. It checks if `route.params` has object `post`.

Comment: Why the question mark in the middle instead of either being omitted or being at the end ?

Comment: nevermind found the documentation by searching optional chaining thanks

Comment: Here you can learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: It is still not running in my node REPL for some reason. Even the official example from MDN.

Comment: Please raise another question specifying what is not running in your code and what you have tried

Comment: Optional chaining is supported in node 14 and above which is the current latest release. Which means that the current LTS version of node which is version 12 does not support it.

Comment: For browsers check out what supports it at caniuse: https://caniuse.com/?search=optional%20chaining

Comment: Ah I am running 12.13.0

Comment: What is strange however is that the expression is not throwing a syntax error in my react-native application ? Maybe it has something to do with Babel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called Optional Chaining. Provided in MDN doc:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

> The optional chaining operator (?.) permits reading the value of a
> property located deep within a chain of connected objects without
> having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is
> valid. The ?. operator functions similarly to the . chaining operator,
> except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish
> (null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value
> of undefined. When used with function calls, it returns undefined if
> the given function does not exist.

`if(route.params.post)` then do something.
It checks if `route.params` has object `post`

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). And it's shorthand for

```
route.params && route.params.post
```